# Classifier based answer ranking Chrome extension

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, data-dump, api, data-analysis

I'm in my final year of a computer science degree. For my thesis I have implemented a classifier that predicts the usefulness of answers to questions with no accepted answer, based on a training set from labeled answers extracted from the Stack Exchange data dump.

I have written a Chrome extension that displays the answers to a question ranked according to the classifier.

I would like to include some user testing, and to that end would like to know if it is appropriate to ask for Stack Overflow users to volunteer as testers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like a good fit for [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/).

That community is explicitly for Stack Exchange-related apps and would doubtless welcome an app with such a lofty goal as predicting the best answer to questions.

---

[Here's a link to the extension on Stack Apps for those interested in giving it a spin](https://stackapps.com/q/3963).